# What is a *slightly* less extreme equivalent to being "fluent" in a language?

Tags: resume

tl;dr: What is a less extreme (but still noticeable) alternative to the word "fluent", when saying e.g. "I am fluent in C++/Python/whatever?"

---

I think I can call myself "fluent" in C#, because I know the language and runtime very well, and I'm very familiar with the .NET framework's APIs and classes, etc.

I would *like* to claim the same thing for Python and C++.
But while I *can* program in Python (I did so for an entire summer, making a website with Django), for example, I would not call myself *fluent* because **my code isn't always "Pythonic"** (e.g. using `map`/`filter` vs. list comprehensions), and I'm not too intimate with some aspects of the language and standard library yet (e.g. the introspection API, etc.).

Is there a word or phrase I can use on e.g. a resume to describe what I know?

I can think of "very familiar with", but is there a better word/phrase I can use?

Comment: of course most people grade themselves as a 7/10 regardless of their actual competency in a subject, I'd expect most interviewers to know this

Comment: @jk.: lol, really? Is this another "45.6% of statistics are made up on the spot", or is there a citation for this? I actually think I'd rate myself 9/10 on some subjects and 3/10 on others...

Comment: can't find one for IT but i'd say this is relevant http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3116466/

Comment: *Conversant* means capable but less than *fluent*. See [my answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/154871/20011) to [At what point can I say I've “learned” a language?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/154862/20011) for a little more detail, but in short: use the same terms you'd use to describe proficiency in a natural language.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Would "proficient" be useful, if not that, "competent".  Both words suggesting a comfort with tasks given within a certain range.

Comment: Oooh yeah they both sound great, I was totally blanking out! Thanks! +1

Comment: Unless you think that "competent" applies in your situation but "proficient" doesn't, I'd recommend "proficient" over "competent".

Comment: @compman: Yeah I agree, I was also going to use "proficient"; thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you are referring to a natural spoken language, one step down from fluent would be "conversant", such as "Fluent in French, conversant in Spanish."

For programming languages, I usually write something like: "Very experienced in C and C++, familiar with Python and C#". But I agree with Irwin that "proficient" seems to be one step below "fluent", so maybe it goes: fluent --> proficient --> familiar.

Answer (score 5):

These are the terms I usually see in real application forms that allow you to pick it from a list:

- Competent
- Skilled
- Experienced
- Good
- Full working capacity/capability

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you are **comfortable** using the language. That does not imply you are an expert.